# mcafee local automatic update

Tags: ftp, anti-virus, intranet, update, mcafee

I'm working in a intranet with 50 machines and I'd like to set up mcafee to have each machine update its engine et virus definitions on a local FTP.

How to set up this configuration and what are the files to download from mcafee website to put on the local FTP?

Arnaud

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this as we run ePO, but I have had a look at it and it should be possible to update from a local FTP.

First you will need to open the VirusScan console and select Tools - Edit AutoUpdate Repository List.

Click "Add" and then fill out the options, you can then select to retrieve files from a HTTP repository, a FTP repository, a UNC path or a local path.

Once you have finished it, click "OK" and then move your new repository up the list to first and you should be right.

You can download your DAT files from ftp://ftp.nai.com/commonupdater/

Answer (score 1):

To add to what **Mr Virus** said, depending on your license with McAfee, you can perhaps get **McAfee Installation Designer**. This will allow you to create a special install package for McAfee suitable for your needs.

You can set the install package to have your preconfigured FTP location in the install so that any new installs will have this automatically.